# hayageek jQuery Upload File Plugin - rename duplicate files

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I just installed this plugin on my website and works like a charm:
http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

My only trouble is that when uploading a file with an existing filename, it overwrites without any warning/alert/renaming.

How can I prevent the file overwriting by showing a message if there is a file with the same name?

think I have to act on upload.php on move_uploaded_file but I can't figure how

```
<?php
//If directory doesnot exists create it.
$output_dir = "../download/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
$ret = array();

$error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];


{

    if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
         //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

             $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
    }
    else
    {
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
          for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
          {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
             $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName );
          }

    }
}
echo json_encode($ret);


}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run a simple [file_exists()](https://www.php.net/file_exists) on the filename before you move it to check if it exists and if it does you just change the filename to something else.

Here is a snippet of code taken from the link above:

```
<?php 
  $img = "images/".$_FILES['bilde']['name'];
  $t=0;
  while(file_exists($img)){
    $img = "images/".$_FILES['bilde']['name'];
    $img=substr($img,0,strpos($img,"."))."_$t".strstr($img,".");
    $t++;
  }
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bilde']['tmp_name'], $img);
?>
```